# Video Playback with DirectX (Direct3D11)

Tags: directx, direct3d, direct3d11

I have been looking over the internet on how to display a video in my Direct3D11 game. In Direct3D9 we could use DirectShow, but I haven't been able to find anything comparable in the new version of Direct3D11.

How would we efficiently display videos in an application in Direct3D11?

I'm targeting Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are using Windows 8, there is an sample to display video by using Media Foundation APIs and DirectX 11, you can take a look.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/DirectX-11-Video-Renderer-0e749100